Expo very slow internet connection requests
i wanted to deploy an expo app. Everything runs nicely on the Simulator, but now I tried it on my android device and the requests takes about a minute for a little request.
Does everyone know what the problem is?
When you simply use the default init npx create-expo-app@latest myApp and then add
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log('lets go')
    fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1').then(() =>
      console.log('done')
    )
  }, [])

in the _layout.tsx file, you will see the "lets go" log, but the done log will take many seconds or minutes. I have tried it with expo@51 but with no success.
